# SilverStripe running tests using Behat throwing "No behat.yml found for module silverstripe/framework" error

Tags: bdd, silverstripe, behat, silverstripe-4

I am working on a SilverStripe project. I am trying to write Behavioural Tests using Behat for my projects. But I am getting an error when I run the tests. Following is what I have done so far.

First I install the module using composer

```
composer require --dev silverstripe/behat-extension
```

I have the behat.yml file right under the project root folder with the following definition

```
default:
  suites: []
  extensions:
    SilverStripe\BehatExtension\MinkExtension:
      default_session: facebook_web_driver
      javascript_session: facebook_web_driver
      facebook_web_driver:
        browser: chrome
        wd_host: "http://127.0.0.1:9515"
      browser_name: chrome
    SilverStripe\BehatExtension\Extension:
      bootstrap_file: vendor/silverstripe/cms/tests/behat/serve-bootstrap.php
      screenshot_path: %paths.base%/artifacts/screenshots
      retry_seconds: 4 # default is 2
```

Then I tried to run the tests executing the following command.

```
vendor/bin/behat @framework
```

Then I get the following error.

```
In ModuleSuiteLocator.php line 166:

  No behat.yml found for module silverstripe/framework  


behat [-s|--suite SUITE] [-f|--format FORMAT] [-o|--out OUT] [--format-settings FORMAT-SETTINGS] [--init] [--namespace NAMESPACE] [--lang LANG] [--name NAME] [--tags TAGS] [--role ROLE] [--story-syntax] [-d|--definitions DEFINITIONS] [--snippets-for [SNIPPETS-FOR]] [--snippets-type SNIPPETS-TYPE] [--append-snippets] [--no-snippets] [--strict] [--order ORDER] [--rerun] [--stop-on-failure] [--dry-run] [--] [<module> [<paths>]]
```

There is not behat.yml in the vendor/silverstripe/framework folder. Actually, it is supposed to come with the framework. But it is not there. How can I solve the error?

Answer (score 1):

For all SilverStripe modules the tests and associated configuration [are not shipped with distributable packages](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/4.5.0/.gitattributes#L1-L10) (e.g. tags).

If you want to use them, you'll need to install the "dev" version. E.g. `4.5.x-dev` instead of `~4.5.0`.